# Ansible get all hosts in subgroup

Tags: ansible, yaml, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts, infrastructure

I have the following hosts structure in the inventory:

```
all:
  children:
    sc:
      hosts:
        sc-finder01a.com:
        sc-finder01b.com:
      vars:
        default_port: 5679
        version: 0.4.2-RELEASE
    ms:
      hosts:
        ms-finder01a.com:
        ms-finder01a.com:
      vars:
        default_port: 5679
        version: 0.4.2-RELEASE
```

I'm running on all hosts, where for each host I'd like to access the other one in the subgroup (sc/ms) in order to check a condition before executing it on the current host, but I'm struggling to find the syntax. Also, I have to prevent Ansible from executing the command on two hosts in the same subgroup in parallel.

Ideas?

Comment: Please edit your question and give some evidence of how you have been "struggling to find the syntax" with an [mcve](/help/mcve). This should shade some light on your actual real life intent and guide people trying to help you in the correct direction for a precise answer. Moreover this should help to rule out a possible [X/Y problem](https://xyproblem.info)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [ansible's special](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html) variables. For controlling execution, check [playbook strategies](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html).

You can access the current host's groups with the group_names variable.  If you want to be in control of host execution order, delegate_to and run_once may help, where you assign a run_once controlling server and delegate tasks looping over the group members list.

Answer (score 0):

Q: ***"Access the other hosts in the subgroup (sc/ms) in order to check a condition before executing it on the current host."***

A: Iterate the list of the hosts in the subgroup(s), e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "Check a condition on {{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ group_names|map('extract', groups)|flatten|unique|
                difference([inventory_hostname]) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] *******************************************************
ok: [sc-finder01b.com] => (item=sc-finder01a.com) => 
  msg: Check a condition on sc-finder01a.com

ok: [sc-finder01a.com] => (item=sc-finder01b.com) => 
  msg: Check a condition on sc-finder01b.com

ok: [ms-finder01b.com] => (item=ms-finder01a.com) => 
  msg: Check a condition on ms-finder01a.com

ok: [ms-finder01a.com] => (item=ms-finder01b.com) => 
  msg: Check a condition on ms-finder01b.com
```

---

**Debug**

The inventory

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
all:
  children:
    sc:
      hosts:
        sc-finder01a.com:
        sc-finder01b.com:
      vars:
        default_port: 5679
        version: 0.4.2-RELEASE
    ms:
      hosts:
        ms-finder01a.com:
        ms-finder01b.com:
      vars:
        default_port: 5679
        version: 0.4.2-RELEASE
```

Display all hosts

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: groups
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] ***************************************************************
ok: [sc-finder01a.com] => 
  groups:
    all:
    - sc-finder01a.com
    - sc-finder01b.com
    - ms-finder01a.com
    - ms-finder01b.com
    ms:
    - ms-finder01a.com
    - ms-finder01b.com
    sc:
    - sc-finder01a.com
    - sc-finder01b.com
    ungrouped: []
```

---

**Multiple subgroups**

The code works also if a host is a member of multiple subgroups, e.g.

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
all:
  children:
    sc:
      hosts:
        sc-finder01a.com:
    ms:
      hosts:
        ms-finder01a.com:
    foo:
      hosts:
        foo-bar.com:
        sc-finder01a.com:
        ms-finder01a.com:
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] ******************************************************
ok: [sc-finder01a.com] => (item=foo-bar.com) => 
  msg: Check a condition on foo-bar.com
ok: [sc-finder01a.com] => (item=ms-finder01a.com) => 
  msg: Check a condition on ms-finder01a.com

ok: [foo-bar.com] => (item=sc-finder01a.com) => 
  msg: Check a condition on sc-finder01a.com
ok: [ms-finder01a.com] => (item=foo-bar.com) => 
  msg: Check a condition on foo-bar.com

ok: [foo-bar.com] => (item=ms-finder01a.com) => 
  msg: Check a condition on ms-finder01a.com
ok: [ms-finder01a.com] => (item=sc-finder01a.com) => 
  msg: Check a condition on sc-finder01a.com
```